# css background-position - png images not displayed as positioned in css

Tags: css, background-position

for some reason the background-position is not working I am trying to set up a variety of planet divs filled with pngs so I can then do some other coding but the images are all appearing stacked atop eachother and some of them are cut up across the div.

CSS:

```
body{
background-image:url('../img/para2/space_bg.jpg');
}

#planet_1{
background:url('../img/para2/planet_1.png');
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:block;
background-position: 400px 400px;
}

#planet_2{
background:url('../img/para2/planet_2.png');
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:block;
background-position: 800px 600px;
}

#planet_3{
background:url('../img/para2/planet_3.png');
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:block;
background-position:450px 700px;
}

#planet_4{
background:url('../img/para2/planet_4.png');
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:block;
background-position:700px 350px;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = en>
<head>
    <title>BASIC PARALLAX MOUSE 2</title>
    <meta charset = "utf8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/para2.css">
    <script src = "java/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "java/jquery_ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id = "planet_1"></div>
    <div id = "planet_2"></div>
    <div id = "planet_3"></div>
    <div id = "planet_4"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

it seems very strange that I cannot position my planets where I want, I'm sure I have the syntax correct on the background-position elements

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any position to your divs.
Try to add this CSS code to one of them:

```
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
```

You'll see it in a different position than the others. Maybe it is what you was trying to do with background-position, but this one is for the position of the background image, not for the HTML element itself.

Hope I could help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Margins do not work on absolutely positioned divs. You need to use top, bottom, left and right - values to position an absolute positioned element. I made a JSFiddle for you so you can mess around changing the left and top values.

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krqtaenL/1/)

Some changes css (only made changes related to absolute positioning and made the divs have a background-color instead of image so you can see what happens in JSFiddle)

```
body{
background-image:url('../img/para2/space_bg.jpg');
}

#planet_1{
background:yellow;
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
top: 250px;
padding:0;
display:block;
background-position: 400px 400px;
}

#planet_2{
background:green;
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
left: 250px;
padding:0;
display:block;
background-position: 800px 600px;
}

#planet_3{
background:blue;
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
left: 250px;
top: 250px;
padding:0;
display:block;
background-position:450px 700px;
}

#planet_4{
background:red;
height:200px;
width:200px;
position:absolute;
margin:100;
padding:0;
display:block;
}
```

Besides that I do not see what you are trying to do with the  background-position values you are using (since they are higher than the divs heights and widths).